# Basic Authentication ComparePassword

Tags: javascript, mongoose, crud, basic-authentication

I am currently working on a "Basic Authetntication" for Node JS. It should accept requests like the following:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate/
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz
```

*The AuthenticationService.js* first reads the header and then passes the whole thing to the Userservice.js

**AuthenticationService.js**

```
async function basicAuth(req, res, next) {
    // make authenticate path public
    if (req.path === '/') {
        return next();
    }

    
    if (!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.indexOf('Basic ') === -1) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Missing Authorization Header' });
    }

    // verify auth credentials
    const base64Credentials =  req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    const [username, password] = credentials.split(':');
    console.log("AuthenticationService "+username+" "+password);
    
    const user = await userService.authenticate({ username, password });
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid Authentication Credentials' });
    }
    req.user=user
    res.send(user)
next();
}
module.exports = {
    basicAuth
}
```

The user service checks if the user is found and checks if the password is valid, only then the user object is sent back to the authentication service.

**UserService.js**

```
async function authenticate({ username, password }) {
    
    
    let user = await User.findOne({userID: username})
        
     user.comparePassword(password.toString(), function(err,isMatch) {
        if (err){
            console.log("error")
            throw err;
        } 
            if(isMatch)
            {
                console.log("Password correct")
                
                
                
            }
            if(!isMatch){
                console.log("Password wrong")
                
                
            }});

if(user){
        return user; 
    }
    else{
        return null;
    } 
    
}

module.exports = {
    
    authenticate
}
```

The *.comparePassword-Method* is inside the **Usermodel.js**:

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};
const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

How can I send the boolean value of **isMatch** in the *Userservice.js* outside it's scope, so I can send the userobject back to the *AuthenticationService.js* depending on the correct password ? How can I improve that code ?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! As I understand, you are asking a question about making some sort of authentication system. My advice to you is to go with a popular and open source library for this. Not only will it make your job easier, it is generally more secure.

Comment: Hi and thank you. But I have to do it like this.

Comment: Okay! Well, maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure where the `user.comparePassword` function comes from. You might need to share that sort of information so that people can properly assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I erase the *authenticate-method* in *Userservice.js* and just call the crud-method. After that I call the *compare-method* and inside the if/else-block I pass a *res.send*.

```
function basicAuth(req, res, next) {
    
    if (!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.indexOf('Basic ') === -1) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Missing Authorization Header'
        });
    }

    // verify auth credentials
    const base64Credentials = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    const [username, password] = credentials.split(':');
    console.log("AuthenticationService " + username + " " + password);

    userService.findUserById(username, function(error, user) {

        user.comparePassword(password.toString(), function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Fehler")
                throw err;
            }
            /*Passwort richtig*/
            if (isMatch) {

                res.send(user);

            }
            /*Passwort falsch*/
            if (!isMatch) {

                res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Passwort und userID stimmen nicht überein.'
                });



            }
        });
    })
}
```